# Word to describe things that run after each other

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, adverbs

Is there a word to describe tasks that need to "run one after the other"? My current choice is *sequentially*, but feel there is a better word.

Comment: [consecutively](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/consecutive)?

Comment: [OneLook Reverse Dictionary](http://onelook.com/?w=*&loc=revfp2&clue=one+after+another): in succession; seriatim; in sequence; sequentially; consecutively; in turn; following each other...

Comment: Thanks, I think "in succession" or "consecutively" are more suitable, I went with "in succession". The OneLook Reverse Dictionary looks like a great resource - thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Consecutively* is for one after the other (in contrast *concurrently* for all at the same time).

The *sequentially* you thought of suggests a particular order. So if you have three things (processes, procedures, whatever) A, B & C and they must happen in order A, B, C (or even if A, B, C and B, A, C are both allowed, but not C, A, B) then *sequentially* would actually be the better word. If you don't care whether it's B, C, A, or any other order - or if there's no meaningful way to even distinguish between the different things - then *consecutively* would be better.